# Построение селекта ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Здравтсвуйте.
Задача: Построить мультиселект с опцией добавления к нему значений юзером. Использую: ACF pro 
Создал отдельно мультиселект,  и  луп через который добавляются значения. По отдельности все работает идеально. Не получается загнать значения из лупа в мультиселект.

```
 //add data to select
 $wtnerd = array();
 function my_tr_acf_load_field( $sub_field, $field, $value)
 {
 global $wtnerd;

   $sub_field['choices'] = $wtnerd;
   return $sub_field;
 }
 add_filter('acf/load_field/key=field_5b57712913942', 
 'my_tr_acf_load_field',20);

 //get data from field   (repeater)

  add_action( 'wp_upd_cst', 'update_custom_field', 10, 2 );
  function my_acf_load_value1( $value, $post_id, $field )
  {
   global $wtnerd;
    for ($i =0;  $i< count($value); $i++){
      $wtnerd[$value]  = $value;
    }
    return $value;
 }
 add_filter('acf/load_value/key=field_5b5846630fd54', 
 'my_acf_load_value1',5,2);
```

Спасибо!